# Second-generation managed packages that have been promoted to released can’t be deleted

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, package, 2gp, delete-managed-package

After attempting to delete a promoted package version I got:

> Second-generation managed packages that have been promoted to released
> can’t be deleted

I wish to delete this promoted package because it has been assigned the wrong namespace. There has to be a way to delete the promoted package version specially if it is the first promoted version and it is still not published in the AppExchange publicly.

Does this require contacting Salesforce Support?

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces are assigned to [packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_package2.htm), not package versions.

You [can't delete](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_package_deletion.htm) a managed second-generation package once you've uploaded a released version, but the good news is you don't really need to. It doesn't do anything sitting in your Dev Hub.

Simply create a new package with the correct namespace and upload a version against that package.

Comment: It is interesting that there is no way to deprecate such a version to prevent installation (something you can do with 1GP).

Comment: @David Reed having several deprecated packages actually makes it confusing to select the right package version in the Partner Community prior to Sec Review